# Reapplying for UK visa with changed circumstances

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I applied for UK tourist visa and got refusal. The reason for refusal is that my salary is low and I can not fund my expenses. Actually, I am travelling with my boyfriend who will pay for all expenses. In my application I mentioned that I will travel alone. Do I have a chance to get a visa, if I re-apply and indicate that I am travelling with my friend who will pay for all travel expenses? Can my friend sign a letter confirming this and document that he has sufficient funds and permanent job and salary?

Comment: Upload a scan of your refusal letter. That is standard operating policy here.

Comment: Further to @PaulofOsawatomie's comment, black out any personal information, such as your name, before uploading.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, face a simple fact: you have lied in the visa application.

Yes, you can reapply and state that your boyfriend will cover all the expenses, but be prepared to receive another refusal, since it may look like you are just looking for a way to get into the UK.

For the future: it is generally very very bad idea to lie in visa applications and to border security officers, especially if you are a genuine visitor.